# Conditional statement not working in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

```
# First Beast battle: If you select the same number as the beast, you win, else, you lose.

beast =$(($RANDOM % 5))
#RANDOM % 5 PICKS A NUMBER BTW 0 AND 4.. 

echo "Your first beast approaches, Prepare to battle.Pick a number between 0 & 4. (0..4)"

read tarnished
if [[$beast == $tarnished]]; then
        echo "Beast VANQUISHED!!! Congrats fellow tarnished. You won!"
else
        echo "You died modafucker!"
fi
```

The above scripts only returns "Beast VANQUISHED!!! Congrats fellow tarnished. You won!" even though I have chosen random numbers different times. Please what could be wrong.

Comment: Remove the space before the equal sign in `beast =$(($RANDOM % 5))`.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I can't reproduce the issue. First I get an error that command `beast` is not found, I put in 2, then I get an error that `[[` is not found and it prints the other message. For debugging help, you'll need to make a [mre]. Try running your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) first and fix any problems it identifies. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: You have a bunch of spacing errors; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point them out.

Comment: I appreciate you @GordonDavisson shellcheck.net was absolutely fantastic. made my work simpler since then.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has a few syntax errors so it isn't running as you expect. First, you can have no space around the `=` in a variable assignment. Second, you *need* spaces around the `[[` and `]]` operators:

```
#!/bin/bash

beast=$(("$RANDOM" % 5))
#RANDOM % 5 PICKS A NUMBER BTW 0 AND 4.. 

echo "Your first beast approaches, Prepare to battle.Pick a number between 0 & 4. (0..4)"

read tarnished
if [[ "$beast" == "$tarnished" ]]; then
  echo "Beast VANQUISHED!!! Congrats fellow tarnished. You won!"
else
  echo "You died modafucker!"
fi
```

Next time, run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for errors.

You could also improve this by adding some basic sanity checks such as ensuring all input is numerical or using bash's `read -p` to prompt:

```
#!/bin/bash

beast=$(("$RANDOM" % 5))
#RANDOM % 5 PICKS A NUMBER BTW 0 AND 4.. 

tarnished=
until [[ "$tarnished" =~ ^[0-4]$ ]]; do
  read -p "Your first beast approaches, Prepare to battle.Pick a number between 0 & 4. (0..4): " tarnished
done

if [[ "$beast" == "$tarnished" ]]; then
  echo "Beast VANQUISHED!!! Congrats fellow tarnished. You won!"
else
  echo "You died modafucker!"
fi
```